# NodeJS+Express: Passport vs OAuth2 in relation to scope (access permissions)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, oauth2orize

Imagine I'm implementing an API service at **api**.example.com that needs to protect its endpoints using OAuth2 with sufficient granularity to accommodate different user types.

- users who authenticate against Facebook can only access https://**api**.example.com/facebook
- users who authenticate against Twitter can only access https://**api**.example.com/twitter
- users who authenticate locally against the Authorization service can access both facebook and twitter endpoints

This means we have the following roles:

- Authentication provider (Authorization server, Facebook, Twitter)
- An Authorization provider (My OAuth2 server) (**auth**.example.com)
- A Resource provider (My API server) (**api**.example.com)
- An ExpressJS webapp or SPA (**www**.example.com), or native app

Questions:

**Q1** How should the application flow be implemented?

My thoughts are ...

A webapp must store the accessToken to **api**.example.com in a session, and send the sessionid to the web browser. If there is no accessToken, it must redirect the browser to **auth**.example.com/login/selectprovider/, providing the client_id="**www**.example.com" and client_secret, and redirect_url="https://**www**.example.com/".

On https://**auth**.example.com/login/selectprovider/ the user selects facebook or twitter or local, and **auth**.example.com redirects the user (again) to /login or facebook or twitter, using the client_id and client_secret and redirect_url=https://**auth**.example.com/**twitter** or https://**auth**.example.com/**twitter** to easily distinguish the three.

Facebook/twitter/local methods will authenticate the user and redirect the browser back to **auth**.example.com.

**auth**.example.com will then generate a (Bearer) accessToken for **api**.example.com and store it together with the user.id into a local database table, with associated scope ("facebook", "twitter" or "local"), put the key (userId) in the browser session and redirect to https://**www**.example.com/

Now when the user clicks on a link in the WebApp, **www**.example.com does a GET or POST on **api**.example.com, providing client_id="www.example.com" client_secret and access_token.

The **api**.example.com endpoints verify the accessToken, and if ok, execute the API and return the value to **www**.example.com that renders it to the browser of the user.

**Q2** Is above the correct flow, or is there a better way?
If correct, how does **api**.example.com validate the accessToken at its endpoints?

Should **auth**.example.com expose a special endpoint for this (eg. /userinfo) that can only be accessed with a client_id="**api**.example.com" and client_secret? That seems expensive to do for each call, but how else could **api**.example.com trust the validity of a token (because it expired or the user logged out)?

What's the OAuth2 standards compliant way?

**Q3** In passport/OAuth2orize examples, I see 3 ways that authentication is validated:

- if (req.user) {...};
- if (req.isAuthenticated()) {...};
- passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false);

**Q4** What does passport.authenticate('facebook') do exactly?

This information is provided in the strategy.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

So this contains the client_id and client_secret. When is this used? Every time passport.authenticate('facebook') is called? Does do the whole redirect to facebook login page, get Authorization code grant and exchange it for an accessToken, store the accessToken internally somehow and keep it until a logout?

It seems unlikely but I don't see how it can actually authenticate the user without all this. And it would be too expensive to do for every API call, so I'm sure it works more efficiently. But I don't know how and studying the source code didn't make it more clear.

**Q5** How does *api**.example.com know when the Bearer accessToken included by *www*.example.com in every API request is not forged or expired?

I assume it has to check it against the **auth**.example.com service, and that service in turn must check if the facebook/twitter session is still valid too, and refresh tokens using the refreshToken at that moment?

Comment: A simple, albeit naive, way would be to use `window.referrer` but this only works on a frontend.

Comment: To which question do you think you provided a useful answer to?

Comment: To verify the current usage scope. As far as I could understand, you want a way to make sure that someone authorized with Facebook as a provider only accesses /Facebook, etc. While making front-end calls, you can use referrer to see where the current URL state or scope is (if implemented).

Comment: I asked how my resource server can know it to manage access to its end points,

Comment: I do not understand. What?

Comment: My question was specifically about Passport.js. The way you can protect endpoints in Express with it is like this:
app.get('/api', 
  passport.authorize('facebook', ...),
  function(req, res, next) => { ... next(); }

But if I must support facebook, twitter, google, etc. then do I have to chain all the strategies? It means if twitter is the last one in the chain, it would have to check the bearer token against all the other providers that are ahead in the chain first, which seems very inefficient, hence my question how to do this properly.